# Can I install an app built for iOS Simulator onto a second simulator?

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, ios-simulator, simulator

I built an app and ran it on the simulator on my Mac (Xcode 4).

I'd like to copy the built app onto a second Mac, also with Xcode 4, just to run the app in the second mac's iOS simulator.

That is, I don't want to have to **build** it on the second mac, just run the app in the second simulator, for presentation purposes (second Mac is connected to big screen in conference room).

I see the app in Debug-iphonesimulator folder, but how to get that onto the second sim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The iPhone simulator stores its apps in `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<OS version>/Applications`, each in a folder named with a GUID. Browse the contents of those folders to find your app, copy the GUID-named folder to the corresponding Applications folder of the other simulator, and you should be set.

Comment: Any idea about how to make possible to manual test localizations with this approach? Because if I do that, when I change the simulator language the app's language does not change, unlike when I do the same from the computer I built the application with Xcode...

Comment: At least as of Xcode 7.3.1 this isn't working for me. When I tar up my app from one Mac and untar it on a second Mac in the right location for the simulator, when I actually reboot the simulator (iOS 9.3, iPhone), the simulator removes the GUID named folder.