# Simulator for iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, testing, mobile

Is there a iOS and an Android Simulator I can use to load up a `IPA` and a `APK` file? I'd like to test the apps but won't have access to the source code. Any software that lets me do that (preferably not on the cloud)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An IPA that wasn’t specifically built for the iOS simulator will have the wrong instruction set and won’t run therein. If you’re in a testing environment and can get whoever’s actually building the code to make a simulator version for you, though, the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267120/can-i-install-an-app-built-for-ios-simulator-onto-a-second-simulator/6269111#6269111) may help.

Answer (score 0):

You can install an android apk through adb on the simulator comes with the Android SDK
[see Google Adb usage](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using bluestacks to install apk files